# Methods to classify observed data into states

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, dataset

Given a time series (that sometimes unpredictably alternates between random and non-random and is not stationary). What mathematical methods are there to *classify the observed set of data into different states*? (preferably analytical methods, i.e. no tools such as machine learning.)

I have tried classifying the data into states by its empirical distribution for a given period, but find that it is very dependent on parameters such as sample length and bin-size (in histogram). Are there any better methods?

Any suggestions very welcome!

Extra info: 
The time series has 3 values for each day. (Analogous to measuring temperature but it has no unit). The TS is about 30000 days long (so a 30000x3 matrix). For every day we are given the "temperature" measured at the same time "every day at 12:00", and the highest- / lowest "temperature" value respectively for that same day. My goal is to divide the TS into different states to better visualize the process, maybe find probabilities of going from one state to another (eg. Markov process), and find states that do not communicate etc.

[Link to sample of 5000 data points.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sa6e4x84vxm6qpi/daily_data_5000_2.csv?dl=0) First column is daily max value, second column is daily minimum value, third is daily measurement at 12:00 and I also added a fourth column (from second csv-file) which is the daily number of observations.

Comment: 30000 days is "scary large" ...Why don't you post say 5,000 days in a csv format & I will see what I can do ( time being available ! )

Comment: @IrishStat Thanks so much for your interest, would be super cool to see what you think! hahah yes, I trimmed it down to 5000 and posted a link in my question above. There are some artifacts e.g. where 9834.70 sometimes gets stored as 9834/70. Hope this is not an issue for you, let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: Unable to process your file [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRUJL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRUJL.png) . Please clean it up . no slashes ... replace them a period . no date needed .. just tell me the beginning date and the end date and make sure there is an entry for every day ..... if you are missing values simply interpolate and place the interpolated values in the file. more pix [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDw4O.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDw4O.png)